# Calling Drain() on a Stream never returns and the stream never closes

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using dart Streams in my Flutter app following the BLOC pattern , so logically whenever i am done with a Bloc , i need to dispose all the streams i have inside it.

So on my dispose method provided by the stateful widget i am calling the drain method like this :

```
dispose() async {
    print('Started Dispose');

    await _mainStream.drain();

    print('_mainStream Drained');
  }
```

So what happens is that i see the first print but never the second one which means my stream is not drained and if i listen to the stream and print something whenever i get a new event, i still see that message in the Debug Console even tho my Bloc is Disposed from the widget tree.

So basically my stream is still there somewhere. How can i solve this issue because its driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop listening on a stream, you cancel your subscription, not call `drain`.
Streams can be "forever", in the sense that they will keep emitting events until they are closed. For this reason, trying to *drain* such streams is dangerous as it will never complete.

Here's a simple example of how you can cancel your subscription:

```
final foreverStream = Stream.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (i) => i);

main() async {
  final subscription = foreverStream.listen((event) => print("EVENT: $event"));  

  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));

  await subscription.cancel();
  print("Done");
}
```

If you'd failed to cancel the subscription, it would just keep printing forever or until you killed the process.

Comment: I also thought about using StreamSubcription and canceling the subscription later on but i thought draining and closing the stream would also work, i will try to implement this approach in my code and get back to you with the result.

Thank you i appreciate the Help :)

Comment: Drain simply listens and discards all events. The future it returns only completes if the stream is closed. If the stream is ongoing (like most are in practice) it will never complete.

Comment: Makes sense since i am listening to a firestore stream, which logically never ends.
I used the StreamSubscription approach and it works perfect, again Thanks for the clarification :D